# Unicode with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, unicode

I have a table with nvarchar field (MS SQL Server 2008 R2). For testing, this code works fine:

```
Update [Screenshots] set name=N'Значение' where id=230246
```

right now I created Entity Framework model, I have set Unicode as True

[image]

then I try to update my record:

```
    public void Put(FormDataCollection formData)
    {
        string filename = formData.Get("filename");
        var screenshot = c.Screenshots.Where(p => p.filename == filename).FirstOrDefault();
        if (screenshot != null)
        {
            screenshot.name = formData.Get("description");
            c.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

but I got "?????" instead of unicode value. How to do it? I know about AsNonUnicode method, but this method works only for LINQ.

Comment: Could the problem be at the database end - and not the EF end?

Comment: as I wrote, Update [Screenshots] set name=N'Значение' where id=230246 works fine. Could I be sure, that problem is not at the database end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Are you sure that `formData.Get("description")` returns UTF-8 string (that it isn't converted somewhere)?
2. What is your approach in entity framework? Code-first/Design-first/Database-first?
   Try to remove database and recreate - remove database and then in designer right click -> `Generate database from model...`
3. Get Entity Framework Profiler from Nu-get package manager and see what query is sending to database.

Comment: "Are you sure that formData.Get("description") returns UTF-8 string?" this is phrased unfortunately. All strings in .NET are Unicode. A better question would be if it returns the string as entered into the form,  i.e. without being mangled by encoding somewhere.

Comment: @millimoose - yes, I meant that :-).

Comment: recreated model and it works right now! seems, EF has "underwater stones". Thank you!

Comment: No problem ;-), after changes in EF designer you should always recreate your database :).