# Storing tamil language text into MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, utf-8, multilingual

Am developing a `tamil` website using `ASP.NET MVC` and `MYSQL`.

1. While updating the values (tamil language text) from ASP.NET MVC website to Database all my values as storing as format like this `??????????????`
2. When I directly run the insert query into my database I am able to insert the tamil text into the database.

Asp.NET MVC : I have the below code

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

MySQL - Create table syntax :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Login` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `password` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Note: I have been using the `Entity Framework` to connect with the MySQL database.

Is any thing missing from my side?

**From Comment**

Solution Found - just add `";Charset=utf8"` to connection string. 
Here is the working solution:

```
<add name="photostorageEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Photos.csdl|
                       res://*/Models.Photos.ssdl‌​|res://*/Models.Photos.msl;
       provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
       provider connection string=&quot;server=ServerIP;
       User Id=UID;password=PASS;
       Persist Security Info=True;database=photostorage; Charset=utf8&quot;" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: Just a little help before some gurus engage.. :)

You should be able to debug your website just before the insert is happening and see the format of your value. Then I could suspect:

1) If the value is in right format, there might be a problem happening when inserting, most likely Entity Framework settings or some other MySQL (DB) settings?

2) If the string is not in the right format just before insert then it would be your website settings and you should see clearly. Can you provide us result of this test? Thank you.

Comment: @VaclavElias - Thanks for ur update. I have debug the website and found that my values are in right format before inserting. Problem occured at the time of inserting.

Comment: At this stage I cannot help because don't have MySQL experience. If it was MS SQL Server then I would use a MS SQL Profiler and see exactly what is happening on the server, also I would use a type nvarchar as a data type for Tamil in case of MS SQL Server. Not sure what should be in MySQL. So now MySQL skilled folks are needed to help you with your answer :-)

Comment: What driver are you using to connect the Entity Framework to MySQL?  Have you verified that it supports UTF-8 connections?

Comment: Also, there was this question earlier this year about the exact thing you're asking, detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258901/unicode-with-entity-framework.  Have you tried what was suggested there?

Comment: Solution Found

All genius is simple. Tooooo simle - jusp add "Charset=utf8" to connection string of Entity
Here is the working solution:

<add name="photostorageEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Photos.csdl|res://*/Models.Photos.ssdl|res://*/Models.Photos.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=ServerIP;User Id=UID;password=PASS;Persist Security Info=True;database=photostorage; Charset=utf8&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>


Thanks for everybody! :)

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the exact same problem.

Add this `connection property` to the `jdbc` driver where you are defining the database connection.

```
<property name="connectionProperties" value="characterEncoding=UTF-8;characterSetResults=UTF-8"/>
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use following query to set the default character set to already created table

```
ALTER TABLE Login CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

You are using collate in multiple places. The following will be enough

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Login` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` text,
  `password` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```