# Entity Framework 6.1.3 and Oracle produces sql with Unicode on NonUnicode column

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, unicode

I'm using the entity framework 6.1.3 with Oracle ManagedDataAccess 12.1.022 and Oracle.managedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12.1.022 (NuGet Packages)(Fig 1). My project is a database first and imports the model to `.edmx` file running T4 code.

Fig 1.[image: Fig 1]

The database uses `varchar2` columns and the `.edmx` file recognizes them as NonUnicode. (Fig 2 & 3)

Fig 2.
[image: Fig 2]

Fig 3.

[image: ![Fig 3]

When running a query, I get an oracle error `ORA-12704: character set mismatch`. This is the query:

```
var emp2 = db.EMPLOYEEs
                .Where(s => s.FIRST_NM.ToUpper().StartsWith(term.ToUpper()) || s.LAST_NM.ToUpper().StartsWith(term.ToUpper()))
                .Select(c => new
                 {
                     label = c.FIRST_NM + " " + c.LAST_NM,
                     value = c.FIRST_NM + " " + c.LAST_NM
                 });
```

Using `.ToTraceString()` I can see that the sql being sent is:

```
SELECT 
1 AS "C1", 
((((CASE WHEN ("Extent1"."FIRST_NM" IS NULL) THEN N'' /* Unicode here for null value */
ELSE "Extent1"."FIRST_NM" END)||(' ')))||(CASE WHEN ("Extent1"."LAST_NM" IS NULL) THEN N''
 ELSE "Extent1"."LAST_NM" END)) AS "C2", 
((((CASE WHEN ("Extent1"."FIRST_NM" IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE "Extent1"."FIRST_NM" END)||(' ')))||(CASE WHEN ("Extent1"."LAST_NM" IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE "Extent1"."LAST_NM" END)) AS "C3"
FROM "RISKMGMT"."EMPLOYEE" "Extent1"
WHERE ((( NVL(INSTR(UPPER("Extent1"."FIRST_NM"), UPPER(:p__linq__0)), 0) ) = 1) OR (( NVL(INSTR(UPPER("Extent1"."LAST_NM"), UPPER(:p__linq__1)), 0) ) = 1))
 /** parameters **/ 
 p__linq__0[System.String] = j

 /** parameters **/ 
 p__linq__1[System.String] = j
```

The `N''` portion of the select clause causes the error. If I remove the `N`, the query will work.  I've found through searching that this was an issue in EF4 but nothing currently. Any idea why this is happening and a way to fix it so the produced SQL will not be Unicode?

Comment: Is there a Unicode setting on your model? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258901/unicode-with-entity-framework

Comment: yes. I updated fig. 3 to show the Unicode property at the bottom is set to false.

Comment: I got a problem with unicode character in query and updating the oracle provider solve the problem. Try odac 12c or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by splitting the query into two different pieces and adding a `.ToArray()` at the end of the first `where` clause. I wanted to return a JSON object so this is my solution.

```
db.EMPLOYEEs
  .Where(s => s.FIRST_NM.ToUpper().StartsWith(term.ToUpper())
           || s.LAST_NM.ToUpper().StartsWith(term.ToUpper()))
 .ToArray();
```

then formating the JSON object:

```
return Json(matching.Select(m => new
        {
            id = m.EMPLID,
            value = m.FIRST_NM + " " + m.LAST_NM,
            label = String.Concat(m.FIRST_NM, " ", m.LAST_NM),
        }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```